Cannot import libraries: how to add Android dependencies using TOML correctly?
I'm still trying to understand Gradle version catalog.
I think the old way to add dependencies is simpler. Edit build.gradle, add stuffs like:
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
}

Sync and done. Those libraries can be imported easily.
And the new way is roughly like this:
lib.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.5.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
material = "1.12.0"
activity = "1.9.0"
constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
sdp-android = "1.1.1"
circleimageview = "3.1.0"

[libraries]
com-intuit-sdp = { group = "com.intuit.sdp", name = "sdp-android", version = "sdp-android" }
de-hdodenhof-circleimageview = { group = "de.hdodenhof", name = "circleimageview", version = "circleimageview" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
ext-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
activity = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity", version.ref = "activity" }
constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }

Sync the gradle. Works OK.
build.gradle
dependencies {

    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.activity
    implementation libs.constraintlayout
    implementation libs.com.intuit.sdp
    implementation libs.de.hdodenhof.circleimageview
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
}

Sync again. Still works OK.
Now I'm having issue with the XML layout, e.g:
  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgProfPic"
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                        android:src="@drawable/img_person"
                        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        app:civ_border_color="#00000000"/>

CircleImageView and @dimen are red-highlighted with these messages:
Class referenced in the layout file, de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView, was not found in the project or the libraries
Cannot resolve symbol '@dimen/_50sdp' 

My understanding is the compiler doesn't know where the import CircleImageView and sdp from. How to fix this?
